# Minecraft Forge 1.16.5 changes since 1.16.4 - compiling error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to learn Minecraft modding, and while following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTo_tzOmukc&list=PLaevjqy3Xufavi5mWXvWnGmwRylL-QZy7&index=5) for version 1.16.4, I found that their code did not work, and I presume this is a change to the API, since I am using 1.16.5.

I have looked at both official and unofficial API docs, but these did not provide me any insight. Could anyone point me to a better API reference, or better yet, to a VSCode extension that autocompletes for the most recent Forge API.

Here is the compile error when I ran `./gradlew.bat build` with my minimal reproducible example (sorry about the code highlighting, I don't know how to fix it):

```
C:\Users\eric\Desktop\Programming\Java\Minecraft Mod 1\src\main\java\com\ericl5445\testmod1\core\init\ItemInit.java:1: error: package net.minecraftforge.item does not exist
import net.minecraftforge.item.Item;
                              ^
C:\Users\eric\Desktop\Programming\Java\Minecraft Mod 1\src\main\java\com\ericl5445\testmod1\core\init\ItemInit.java:2: error: package net.minecraftforge.item does not exist
import net.minecraftforge.item.ItemGroup;
                              ^
```

Here is my full code:
[TestMod1.java](https://pastebin.com/Pz3jCRHm)
[ItemInit.java](https://pastebin.com/mu9dyUuh)

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have an api reference, however I have found that the ItemGroup class is not under *net.minecraftforge.item*. It is under the package **net.minecraft.item**.

Your IDE, usually Intellij Idea or Eclipse, should be able to tell you where these classes are located via a search functionality. In Eclipse, you can press Control/Command + Shift + T to bring up a search box with a list of all the classes in your workspace.

Comment: I really would like to continue using VSCode, but I will switch as a last resort. Do you know where I could find a list of those classes (i.e. documentation), or if I could export those classes from an IDE with Minecraft Forge support, as a makeshift documentation? I'm thinking it might be wiser just to switch, but want to make sure it is the only option first.

Comment: I don't have a lot of time to debug today, but I just tried compiling my mod, and your solution fixed the problem I was having, but I have a similar problem, with not using the right classes. However, I think your solution is acceptable, so I have accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

The Package You Need To import is net.minecraft.item.Item and net.minecraft.itemGroup,
Not net.minecraftforge.item.Item and net.minecraftforge.itemGroup